# How to deploy Bottle app on uWSGi using Emperor Mode

Tags: python, nginx, uwsgi

I m trying to deploy a Bottle App using the uWSGi in Emperor mode.

demo.py

```
import os
from bottle import Bottle, route, run

app=Bottle()

@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return "Hello world! "

@app.route('/:name')
def hello(name):
    return "hello %s" % name

# Mod WSGI launch
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(file))
application = bottle.default_app()
```

demo.ini

```
[uwsgi]
# Variables
base = /opt/apps/webapp/demo
app = demo
# Geneic Config
plugins=http,python
home = /opt/apps/webapp/demo
pythonpath=%(base)
socket = /tmp/%n.sock
module = %(app)
logto = /var/log/uwsgi/%n.log
```

The out put in the log file

```
gracefully (RE)spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 2414)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 2646, cores: 1)
[pid: 2646|app: -1|req: -1/1] 10.0.0.240 () {40 vars in 688 bytes} [Sat Oct 13 15:00:00 2012] GET /demo => generated 48 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 63 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
announcing my loyalty to the Emperor...
[pid: 2646|app: -1|req: -1/2] 10.0.0.240 () {40 vars in 688 bytes} [Sat Oct 13 15:00:05 2012] GET /demo => generated 48 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 63 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
[pid: 2646|app: -1|req: -1/3] 10.0.0.240 () {42 vars in 719 bytes} [Sat Oct 13 15:00:26 2012] GET /demo => generated 48 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 63 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
```

But on browser i still see this error

```
uWSGI Error

Python application not found
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I finally able to found the answer and it seems it has been a silly mistake.
I was calling

```
http://localhost/demo
```

where as it should be

```
http://localhost/demo/demo
```

i.e.

```
http://localhost/{app_name}/{route_name}
```